# How to link to current document's folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a workflow using SP Designer. I'm not at Visual Studio level. An email gets sent out when a new doc is added to a library with many different folders and levels.

It's easy to link the document url in the email using `EncodeAbsoluteUrl` property of the item so that they can open it from the link, but,

**How do I give them a link to the containing folder in case they don't want to actually launch the doc, they just want to see where it went?**

Again there are many folders and levels of folders in this library, so I can't just link the library url itself and dump them off there.

This has proven to be a little tricky for me and if anyone has had to do this before and pulled it off in SP Designer, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would make sure this functionality is actually needed... you might be over-engineering when the users don't actually need it (it is a good idea though, my point is just don't make something overly complex if it's not required by the users, who as we all know often have much simpler expectations than IT pros).

For the actual code, you need to do the below bit of messy string work:

[image]

1. First we replace the %20 occurrences with spaces, because otherwise we won't get a match between the Name value and Encoded URL (because the former doesn't include encoded spaces, but the latter does)
2. Next we find the index position of Name within our un-encoded URL value
3. Finally we get the number of characters from the start of the string equal to the index position (or you could extract it from the Encoded URL if you need the URL encoded in the email, but it shouldn't matter as if you access an SP URL with spaces in it auto-encodes them anyway)

Hope that helps, I've tested it and it brings back the expected data.

Comment: over engineering comment well received and I totally agree, but they asked for it. I was thinking along the same lines of what you are suggesting, but it seems like even if I get filename and concatenate with file type (ext) and use that in a string replace operation it seems as though there is a version number in the url as well when using encodedAbsoluteURL

Comment: if I could just find a way to get to first / when going from end to front, I would be all set, but I can't see how to do that in SP Designer's string operations

Comment: I'm working on a solution at the moment, think I've cracked it with some sneaky string replace ops... will post a screenshot shortly.

Comment: Answer updated, you should be good to go now.

Comment: looks like it will work, let me try it. thx

Comment: I only ended up getting the domain address www.xxx.com, could that have something to do with replacing %20 with _ ?

Comment: Can you show me the exact code you're using? May be down to the specific item properties. A screenshot of sample values for Encoded URL and Name would also help (do a simple workflow that puts these to the History list just to confirm they look like as expected).

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, and I hope you can edit your answer above so I can mark it as accepted. Instead of unencoding the whole absoluteURL, which would need to be re-encoded again before becoming link, I replaced _ with %20 in current item name, and then used THAT for a find on encodedAbsoluteUrl